# Why should I consider the complementary probability if I can do it directly?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have this homework problem:

"Suppose that $n$ independent trials, each of which results in any of the outcomes $0$, $1$, or $2$, with respective probabilities $0.3$, $0.5$ and $0.2$, are performed. Find the probability that both outcome $1$ and outcome $2$ occur at least once. (Hint: Consider the complementary probability)"

Here I don't get why they're telling you to consider the complementary probability. Can't you do it directly with the info given already. I tried and couldn't find a direct approach. So I would like an explanation on why the complementary probability works and not the direct one.

Comment: You can certainly *do* it directly, but it’s much more convenient algebraically to do it with the complement. I bet if you try writing out your direct solution, you’ll see why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the complement can be stated as "only outcome 3 occurs" and this is easier to work with (can be done in one formula), while the direct way needs cases (and maybe considering the intersection in overcounting etc.). You don't *need* to do it but it *is* easier to do it.

The direct way involves a lot more counting: at least one position where 1 occurs and at least one (different from the first) where 2 occurs and indifferent on the other outcomes etc. The complement is much easier once you realise what it says.

Comment: The complement of "both outcome 1 and outcome 2 occur at least once." is not "only outcome 0 occurs". It's "Either only 0 or 1 occurs, or only 0 or 2 occurs" There is some inclusion-exclusion going on here as well, just to make matters more interesting. It's still loads easier than trying to go for the direct approach, though.

Comment: -1. The complement is missing some more outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

Direct method also works, but it gets longer with larger $n$. You need to consider all possible outcomes (which is called brute forcing).

Let $X,Y,Z$ be the number of times the outcomes $0,1,2$ occur in $3$ trials, respectively. We need to find $P(Y\ge 1 \ \text{and} \  Z\ge 1)$.

Direct method:
$$\begin{align}n=3:& \quad P(1,1,1)+P(0,1,2)+P(0,2,1)=\\
&\quad =3!\cdot 0.3\cdot 0.5\cdot 0.2+3\cdot 0.5\cdot 0.2^2+3\cdot 0.5^2\cdot 0.2=0.39.\\
n=4:& \quad \small{P(2,1,1)+P(1,1,2)+P(1,2,1)+P(0,1,3)+P(0,2,2)+P(0,3,1)=\cdots} \end{align}$$
Complement method:
$$P(Y\ge 1 \ \text{and} \ Z\ge 1)=1-P(Y=0 \ \text{or} \ Z=0)=\\
1-[P(Y=0)+P(Z=0)-P(Y=0 \ \text{and} \ Z=0)];\\
\begin{align}n=3:& \quad 1-\left[{3\choose 0}0.5^3+{3\choose 0}0.8^3-{3\choose 3}0.3^3\right]=0.39\\
n=4:& \quad 1-\left[{4\choose 0}0.5^4+{4\choose 0}0.8^4-{4\choose 4}0.3^4\right]=0.536\\
\vdots \\
n=k:& \quad 1-\left[{k\choose 0}0.5^k+{k\choose 0}0.8^k-{k\choose 4}0.3^k\right].\end{align}$$